# Trying to invert binary numbers in java

Tags: java, binary, flip

I want to invert binary representation of a number.

The method in the program receives a 6 character hex color code via the parameter col. It should convert this value to its binary counterpart(e.g. 1111 becomes 0000 amd vice versa) and then flip all the bits. This new value should then be converted back to its hexadecimal equal. This will produce a color inversion of the original color image.

My incomplete code,

```
public String invertColor(String col)
    {
        String inverted = col;

        int i = Integer.parseInt(inverted, 16);
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        System.out.println(bin);

        return inverted;

}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why the conversion to bits in a string? Just do `colour ^= 0xFFFFFF`?

Comment: I don't see much effort put in here, I suggest you try harder before asking for help. Read the Javadoc for String and Integer, and read about the bitwise operators.

Comment: In case you did not understand the answer above (by harold) go to http://www.c4learn.com/javaprogramming/bitwise-xor-bitwise-operators-in-java-programming/.

Comment: i had more code but decided not to include it because i didnt think it would be of use

Answer (score 7):

You can use the bitwise NOT operator `~` to flip your bits. The following method demonstrates this:

```
public String invertColor(String col)
{
    String inverted = col;

    int i = Integer.parseInt(inverted, 16);
    i = ~i;
    inverted = Integer.toHexString(i);
    inverted = inverted.substring(2);
    return inverted;
}
```